# Select post id where some values are true and sort them with a value among them

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Age-old question([#1](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/29447), [#2](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/147757/22728)), I still am struggling with the issue. Now trying with a simple SQL Query:

```
global $wpbd;
$post_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'posts';
$meta_table = $wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta';
$fs_query = "SELECT $post_table.ID
                FROM $post_table
            INNER JOIN $meta_table
                ON ( $post_table.ID = $meta_table.post_id )
            WHERE 1=1
                AND $post_table.post_type = 'services'
                AND $post_table.post_status = 'publish'
                AND (
                    $meta_table.meta_key = 'example_featured'
                    AND $meta_table.meta_value = 1
                    )
                AND $meta_table.meta_key = 'example_sort'
            GROUP BY $post_table.ID
            ORDER BY $meta_table.meta_value+0 ASC
            LIMIT 0, 8";
            my_var_dump($fs_query);
```

#### TABLE 1 : wp_posts

```
+------------+--------------+----------------+
|     ID     |   post_type  |   post_status  |
+------------+--------------+----------------+
|     1      |   services   |     publish    |
+------------+--------------+----------------+
```

#### TABLE 2 : wp_postmeta

```
+------------+------------+------------------+--------------+
|     ID     |   post_id  |     meta_key     |  meta_value  |
+------------+------------+------------------+--------------+
|     1      |      1     | example_featured |       1      |
|     2      |      1     | example_sort     |       5      |
+------------+------------+------------------+--------------+
```

Struggling with making this SQL query:
I want all the post_id where `post_type` = 'services', and `post_status` = 'publish', and the value for the associate `meta_value` (`example_featured`) is 1 (one). And then want to sort the result using another meta value I passed using another `meta_key` (`example_sort`). If I remove `AND $meta_table.meta_key = 'example_sort'` from the query then get those post IDs, but with the query above I get nothing at all.

How can I do it?

Comment: This is unrelated to your original question but there are properties for the posts and postmeta table. Change `$wpdb->prefix . 'posts'` to `$wpdb->posts` and `$wpdb->prefix . 'postmeta'` to `$wpdb->postmeta`.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#Tables

Comment: Thank you. I did it because in one of my project it's creating problem with the prefix. :) BTW without that it's still working. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are already doing a `group by`, so you can approach this using conditional aggregation.  This means moving some of the conditions to a `having` clause.  I also introduced table aliases -- they make queries easier to write and to read:

```
SELECT p.ID
FROM $post_table p INNER JOIN
     $meta_table m
     ON (p.ID = m.post_id )
WHERE p.post_type = 'services' AND
      p.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY p.ID
HAVING SUM(m.meta_key = 'example_featured' AND m.meta_value = 1) > 0
ORDER BY MAX(CASE WHEN m.meta_key = 'example_sort' then m.meta_value end)
LIMIT 0, 8;
```

This is an example of a set-within-sets query -- that is, you are looking at logic for all the meta keys for a given post.  The logic has two pieces, the filtering piece (on "example_featured") and the ordering piece (on "example_sort").  The problem you faced is that this information is on two different rows in the meta table.

The `HAVING` clause counts the number of rows that meet the condition on "example_featured".  If any are encountered, the `SUM()` is greater than 0.  As an aside, if you wanted to guarantee that the value was *never* there, then you would use `= 0` rather than `> 0`.

The `ORDER BY` clause extracts the value from the row where the key is "example_sort".  If there is more than one match, then the maximum value is used.  If there are no matches, then the result of the `MAX()` expression is `NULL`, and sorted accordingly.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, bulls eye. BTW I'm new to SQL syntax and you introduced some more new like 'HAVING', 'CASE WHEN', 'then', 'end'. If it's not bad for me, would you please explain the query a bit. Anyways, I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: Kudos to your effort. Thank you very much.